# PHP/MySQL - Select all the rows where column from table 1 is equal to column from table 2

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for a way that i can select all the rows from MySQL table where column from table1 is equal to column from table 2.

Here is what i want to achieve describing it by code. I tried this but nothing happens.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC;
```

Can you give me a correct way to make this thing happen as an answer to my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing a `from` clause.  More importantly, the backticks are incorrect . . . and not needed.  And, the proper way is to use `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id = table2.id
ORDER by table1.name ASC;
```

When you have an expression such as `table1.id` in backticks, then it is looking for a column name called exactly that -- with a period in the middle.  It is *not* looking for `id` in `table1`.  If you use backticks, then you need to include them around the table name and column name separately:

```
`table1`.`id`
```

But, I would suggest not using them and naming tables and columns so they are unnecessary.  They are cumbersome to type and awkward to read.

Comment: But then if i have foreach how can i echo the `table2.name` and `table1.name` ? If you get me what i mean ?

Comment: @TonyStark . . . I think you need to use aliases . . . `select table1.name as name1, table2.name as name2 from . . .`.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with that addition ? With the explanation what to do when i will use foreach ?